# Can I mine Quark on Linux?

Tags: miner-configuration, linux, mining-software, quarkcoin

Are there any Linux applications for mining Quark coin? I am running CPU Coin Miner and I have the Quark Wallet, both on Windows, but I would like to install these on Ubuntu or some Linux distro. Is this possible?

Comment: What I've yearned for a long time is for a comparison of mining profitbility becoming available for CPU-only coins as quark, prime, protoshares and their kin...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are multiple open source mining clients stated in the [Quarkcoin thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=260031.0). See "standalone miners".